# If $z=(6-2i)(4-7i)$, find $z^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z=(6-2i)(4-7i)$, find $z^2$

I got
$$- 5.5 - 4.5i \quad\text{for}\; n=0$$ 
$$\phantom{-}5.5 + 4.5i \quad\text{for}\; n=1$$

Answer required in polar and rectangular form.

Comment: For "n=0" and for "n=1"...  What does $n$ have anything to do with the question of finding $((6-2i)(4-7i))^2$?

Comment: Where do decimals come in when multiplying Gaussian integers?

Comment: I'm re-learning maths for an exam and am not very well versed in complex numbers - think high school minimal understanding. I thought this required De Moivre's Theorem to complete and I'm guessing that's not the case?

Comment: If $z = (6-2i)(4-7i)$, then  $z = 6(4-7i)-2i(4-7i)=24-42i-8i-14=10-50i$ and $z^2 = z \cdot z = (10-50i)(10-50i)=10(10-50i)-50i(10-50i)=\cdots =-2400-1000i$.

Comment: It doesn't have to require De Moivre's theorem, depending on how willing you are to do slightly-tedious algebra.

Comment: Given the answer in the attempt... I can only imagine that the OP either made a big typo when writing the question and asked for $z^2$ when he really meant to ask for $z^{1/2}$, or the OP misunderstands the problem being asked.  That being said, use equals signs *only for equality*, never for approximations.  Use exact results whenever possible otherwise.  Plugging in the numbers and finding $z^{1/2}$, the principle value would be closer to $\approx 5.5222366\dots - 4.52715\dots i$

Comment: Yes, that is all well and fine, $z$ is $10-50i$ as you say... and you are active in the comments and actively editing.  Now... please respond to the following question.  Did you want to **square** the number $z$?  Or did you want to **square-root** the number $z$?  These are two very different operations.  The problem as written looks like you want to square it.  Your attempt looks like you tried to square root it (*and you came close to the answer for that problem, but you have an issue with your signs and using approximations where you shouldn't*)

Comment: I wanted two answers.. I think

Comment: You are given $z$, not $z^2$. You have $z=10-50i$, now you simply must square it for your answer. This doesn't require de Moivre's identity (IMO, makes it more complicated than necessary too). EDIT: And of course, conversion between rectangular and polar for your answer for $z^2$ to get the other part of the answer is about the same as any other conversion.

Comment: I'm new to this and not great at structuring my questions and responding promptly as I'm on a mobile. I appreciate your help and I understand not approximating until the end of an operation I just did it to get through it quickly to see if my method is correct

Comment: So the answer is as simple as squaring z?

Comment: If you are given $z$, and you are asked what is $z^2$ given that knowledge then you simply square $z$.  Now... if on the other hand you were given $z^2$ and you were asked to find $z$ given that knowledge, then you would square root $z^2$.

Comment: Yup. Square $z$, FOIL like you would when multiplying binomials, and you have $z^2$ in rectangular coordinates. To get in polar, just use the usual conversion method of your preference.

Comment: Wow, okay. Thanks a lot. Very much so appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize comments:

You found correctly that $(6-2i)(4-7i)=10-50i$

Now, if we are given that $z=10-50i$ and we are interested in finding what the value of $z^2$ is, then we want to square $z$ which would give us $(10-50i)^2 = -2400-1000i$, found by just expanding the product using the usual "FOIL" method, or however you are comfortable expanding products.

On the other hand, if we are given that $z=10-50i$ and we are interested in finding what the values of $z^{1/2}$ are, that is when we would square root $z$.  To do so, this is when you might invoke DeMoivre's theorem, and the results would be approximately $5.52 - 4.52 i$ and $-5.52+4.52i$.  You seem to have missed a negative sign somewhere in your attempt.